# LWC1513: @salesforce/resourceUrl modules only support default imports

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I am trying to import a 3rd party javascript library into my LWC and everytime I try to push the code to my Scratch Org, I get the below error.

> LWC1513: @salesforce/resourceUrl modules only support default imports.

The library consists to 2 files:

1. A javascript file
2. A CSS file

I have zipped these 2 files into one and uploaded them as a static resource. I use the below code in the js file of my LWC:

```
import { Library } from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CustomLibrary';
```

The static resource has the name 'CustomLibrary' in my org. The push succeeds without this line of code though. I spent enough time to figure out what is going wrong but with little success.

I came across a similar link on Stack Overflow, but that didn't help me either.

Comment: remove the curly braces around Library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default imports dont use curly braces, therefore, your import would be as follows:

`import Library from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CustomLibrary';`

this is standard across library imports from the static resource library.

for a more in depth explanation, you can refer to the [Javascript Reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults)

and the LWC Documentation on [Accessing Static Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_resources)

Comment: Also, LWC docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_resources

Comment: yup - included the link as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @glls, it helped me resolve my issue. So silly of me. I knew it had to be something very simple. I wish I had figured it out on my own.